# Javascript variable value doesn't update the way it should

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm refactoring a black jack card game I wrote in javascript a while back. The original version was written very procedurally and looked amateurish so I am redoing it OOP style -- this is the first time I've ever tried to write OOP. I've included a link to an excerpt of my code that doesn't seem to be working. I've only included the most pertinent code because the whole script is hundreds of lines long.

Essentially, I have a prototype called Betting that contains all the wager-based functions that I need for my game. I have another prototype called GameUI that registers all my click events in the game -- actions like 'deal', 'hit', stay, wagers, etc ...

Please look at the function I wrote in Betting called updateWager(). I created it and called it in GameUI.wagerEvents(). I can't get the value of this.playerWager to ever be anything than its initial value of zero. I know there's nothing wrong with:

```
        this.playerWager += parseInt(value, 10);
```

because it worked in my previous version of the code, and I've gotten it to work in this code but only by using global scope on the variable assignment, and I don't want that, obviously. Any help I can get to figure this out would be amazing.

Thanks!

http://jsbin.com/nokim/1/edit

Comment: Put all the relevant code *in* the question, not just linked. People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: in the `wagerEvents` function, can you log `chipValue` to verify that it is not `0`?

Comment: @adrift42, yes. I have consoled that and the issue is never with chipValue. It's always with player wager returning a value of zero

Comment: Running a stripped down version of your Betting class and prototype in the node REPL it works just fine.  The return value is the same as the console.log statement inside the prototype.

Comment: @HeadCode, weird, whenever i console i always get the value of the chip i clicked on. So if i click on a 100 wager and then a 50, I get 100 and 50 logged to the console  respectively. Instead it should be adding them. In that case i should return a value of 150.

Comment: OK, let me try a more comprehensive attempt...

Comment: heyjohnmurray: you are creating a new betting object inside of GameUI.wagerEvents() by writing the statement var betObj = new Betting(); 
This creates an object local to the wagerEvents function, as you know Javascript has function scope. Instead you should use the existing betObj object defined in the GameUI definition.

Comment: @Aravind, can you show me an edited version of that so that i can understand what you're saying. It makes sense but code will make it click for me. Because when I remove the instance of Betting() in wagerEvents(), I get an error of undefined.

Comment: @heyjohnmurray: like this
http://jsbin.com/busivogefo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: change is like this:

wagerEvents: function(e){
        var chipValue = e.target.dataset.value;
        this.primaryButtonsShown();
        this.betObj.updateWager(chipValue);
        this.betObj.cashOnHand();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: @Aravind, that makes perfect sense. Dang. I knew it was a scope issue and i did think about using the object  in gameui but couldn't figure out how. So can you explain exactly why the value was never updating? I'll go chamfer my code layer today and see if your suggestion works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aravind, you were right except the gameUI Betting reference needed its syntax tweaked.

```
function GameUI(){
    //var betObj = new Betting();
    this.betObj = new Betting(); // it should be this instead
    this.registerDomElements();
    this.registerWagerEvents();
    this.registerDealButtonEvent();
    this.registerHitButtonEvent();
    this.registerStayButtonEvent();
    betObj.renderStartingTotalCash();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this change is needed as well, since, when you do var betObj = new Betting(), BetObj is a local variable to the function invocation, and hence gets life when function is called, and dies when the function call is done. When you write this.betobj = new Betting(), the betObj property is created on the *this* object, which is the execution context for the function call. When new operator is used, the execution context is set to the newly created object.